ChartJS / react-chartjs-2 divide bar in to two data points
I am creating a barchart with ChartJS / react-chartjs-2.
The barchart is displaying allright so far, nothing special:

My data looks like this:
    {
      Name: "De Regenboog",
      Patients: "7546",
      Year1Total: "34",
      Year1Pos: "4",
      Year2Total: "51",
      Year2Pos: "1",
      Year3Total: "43",
      Year3Pos: "0",
    },
    {
      Name: "George Michael",
      Patients: "2644",
      Year1Total: "20",
      Year1Pos: "0",
      Year2Total: "18",
      Year2Pos: "0",
      Year3Total: "64",
      Year3Pos: "0",
    },
   etc
  ]

I want the positives to display as a part of the total bar of that year for that Name.
So for 'De Regenboog' in the year 2021 it would show the total bar to be 34 and 4 would be coloured in differently to be the positive tests that year. I am not sure what to search for or how to approach this. Would it be possible at all ? Maybe anyone has an idea?
Update for clarity, this is how I want the data for 1 practice for 1 year to stack. But I want to have three years per practice displayed. I also cant get it to work in Google Sheets so im uncertain if it is possible:


You can set a backgroundColor for each dataset entry to create a visual distinction between the positive cases and the rest of the totals within the same bar, so if your data looks like this:
const dataSet = [
    {
      Name: "De Regenboog",
      Patients: "7546",
      Year1Total: "34",
      Year1Pos: "4",
      Year2Total: "51",
      Year2Pos: "1",
      Year3Total: "43",
      Year3Pos: "0",
    },
    {
      Name: "George Michael",
      Patients: "2644",
      Year1Total: "20",
      Year1Pos: "0",
      Year2Total: "18",
      Year2Pos: "0",
      Year3Total: "64",
      Year3Pos: "0",
    },
   etc
  ];

You can label dataSets entries in different colors like this:
const data = {
  labels: dataSet.map(entry => entry.Name),
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Year1 Positives',
      data: dataSet.map(entry => parseInt(entry.Year1Pos)),
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
    },
    {
      label: 'Year1 Total Minus Positives',
      data: dataSet.map(entry => parseInt(entry.Year1Total) - parseInt(entry.Year1Pos)),
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
    },
    {
      label: 'Year2 Positives',
      data: dataSet.map(entry => parseInt(entry.Year2Pos)),
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.5)',
    },
    {
      label: 'Year2 Total Minus Positives',
      data: dataSet.map(entry => parseInt(entry.Year2Total) - parseInt(entry.Year2Pos)),
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.5)',
    },
    {
      label: 'Year3 Positives',
      data: dataSet.map(entry => parseInt(entry.Year3Pos)),
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.5)',
    },
    {
      label: 'Year3 Total Minus Positives',
      data: dataSet.map(entry => parseInt(entry.Year3Total) - parseInt(entry.Year3Pos)),
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.5)',
    },
  ],
};

NOTE: Make sure you change 'dataSet' to your dataset name, if named differently.
*** UPDATE
The following code should provide your requirements:
const data = {
  labels: dataSet.map(entry => entry.Name),
  datasets: [
    {
      label: '2021 Positives',
      data: dataSet.map(entry => parseInt(entry.Year1Pos)),
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
      stack: '2021'
    },
    {
      label: '2021 Non-Positives',
      data: dataSet.map(entry => parseInt(entry.Year1Total) - parseInt(entry.Year1Pos)),
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
      stack: '2021'
    },
    {
      label: '2022 Positives',
      data: dataSet.map(entry => parseInt(entry.Year2Pos)),
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.5)',
      stack: '2022'
    },
    {
      label: '2022 Non-Positives',
      data: dataSet.map(entry => parseInt(entry.Year2Total) - parseInt(entry.Year2Pos)),
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.5)',
      stack: '2022'
    },
    {
      label: '2023 Positives',
      data: dataSet.map(entry => parseInt(entry.Year3Pos)),
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.5)',
      stack: '2023'
    },
    {
      label: '2023 Non-Positives',
      data: dataSet.map(entry => parseInt(entry.Year3Total) - parseInt(entry.Year3Pos)),
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.5)',
      stack: '2023'
    }
  ],
};

const options = {
  scales: {
    x: {
      stacked: true,
    },
    y: {
      stacked: true,
    }
  },
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'top'
    }
  }
};

And, here is a link to a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/santi-chart-m672m2

Thank you for helping! I think it won't stack the totals and positives for the given year and group the three years per practice like that? Or am I implementing it wrong? I've added an image of an example to my question - showing it with one year only. That I get to work in Google Sheets (not in ChartJS). But I would like it to have the other two years next to it, stacked in similar fashion.

Happy to help! I will update my answer so you can have a stacked bar for each year with a visual distinction between the positive cases and the rest of the totals within the same bar, grouped for each name. I included a link to a sandbox with a working example.

It works! Thank you so much, really appreciate the help and I understand it now :) am going to implement it!

Awesome! Glad I could help :) All the best.
